# Inotify propertychanged not updating

Tags: windows-phone-7, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class which implements inotifypropertychaned.

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _name = string.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            this._name = value;
            onPropertyChanged(this, "Name");
        }
    }

    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

        }
    }
}
```

here in UI i ve a textbox where a textchanged event when the length exceeds and updates the UI(grid) which binds the observable collection of the above mentioned class. but the UI is not updating.

```
    ObservableCollection<Item> lstItem = null;


private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        try
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 4)
            {
                Item obj = new Item();
            obj.Name = textBox1.Text;
            lstItem = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = lstItem;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
Item obj = new Item();
obj.Name = textBox1.Text;
lstItem = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = lstItem;
```

You're setting the data source to an *empty* collection each time, and you're creating a new `Item` and then throwing it away again. Did you intend to add the item to the collection?

```
lstItem = new ObservableCollection<Item> { obj };
```

(It's not really clear whether you *should* be creating a new collection or even a new item - perhaps you should be using something like:

```
lstItem[0].Name = textBox1.Text;
```

instead?)

Comment: yes i intend to add. but then if i add the object of a class. its pretty much a straight forward ryt. then whats is the need of using inotifypropertychanged in the class(item). is that justified using it?

Comment: @BharathNadadur: I'm not sure what you mean by "straight forward ryt" - but if you're not modifying a property on an *existing* object which is already displayed, there's really not a lot of point in notifying anyone of property changes... hence the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: This one lstItem[0].Name = textBox1.Text gives the 'index out of range exception'

Comment: This part of code always shows null and its not going inside the if loop if (handler != null)

Comment: @BharathNadadur: Well I was assuming you would populate the collection with an initial value, which would solve the first problem. Then I'd *expect* that when you bound the collection, the property notification handler would be subscribed by the control...

Comment: So whats the exact usage of propertychanged

Comment: I have a scenario which needs to refresh the listbox in my wp7 app when the textbox text gets changed. but the list is not refreshing so i googled and found out that notifypropertychanged could well be the workaround for this. Can u provide me a sample of the class implementing notifypropertychanged interface which inturn updates the UI

Comment: @BharathNadadur: I'm afraid I haven't got time to provide a full example, but I'd expect there to be plenty of tutorials around. The important point is that there has to be a control already bound to the item *before* the property changes, otherwise there's no point.

Comment: thanks Jon. One final thing. Does inotifycollectionchanged also works the same way as propertychanged..?

Comment: @BharathNadadur: Similarly, yes - it basically notifies a listener when items are added, removed or replaced.

Comment: thanks jon. can i have u on skype cos i'm pretty new to wp7 so i may get your assistance if get held up with any issues.